# Using getSheetByName() with a var inserted in ui.prompt()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do a specific action on a sheet the user enter it's name in a dialog box. For some reason, `getSheetByName` doesn't get the var with the text the user inserted in the dialog box. See code below - what am I doing wrong?

```
function appendSheet() {
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var sheetToCopy = ui.prompt('Sheet To Copy');
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetToCopy);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

`ui.prompt` returns an instance of the [PromptResponse Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response) but you want to get the text the user provides in the input field.

- You need to use the [getResponseText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response#getResponseText()) to get the text that the user entered in the dialog's input field.

### Solution:

```
function appendSheet() {
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var sheetToCopy = ui.prompt('Sheet To Copy').getResponseText(); // Modified code
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetToCopy);

   sh.getRange('A1').setValue('Hello World'); // example use case
}
```